# FTP server to store user information and logs in database

Tags: gratis, database, logs, ftp, server

I am looking for a free FTP server that stores in database (I would prefer MySQL):

- user information
- logs (connections, commands, downloads, uploads)

If it can work on Windows, it would be nice.

I have seen that the [Apache FTP Server](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/) can store [user information in MySQL](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/configuration_user_manager_db.html), but I haven't seen if it can store logs into it too.

Comment: What kind of user information you would like to store in database?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware about FTP server which can store log and traces directly to the database. But there is an option to ask your logging subsystem store data to database. For instance, [rsyslogd](http://www.rsyslog.com/) have a pluggable modules to store log entries to SQL database (MySQL, PostgreSQL). So, if any FTP server of your choice supports logging via syslog protocol, then log entries could be stored in SQL database.

You might find [this blog post](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/tutorials/database.html) useful.

Unfortunately, rsyslogd can't run on Windows, but have a Windows agent for integration purposes with rsyslogd daemon running on server (e.g. Linux).

Comment: Thanks. I would have liked a simpler solution, but if there is no other solutions...